# how can i echo individual elements from this array

Tags: php, arrays, pdo, stdclass

i have an `array` which i obtained from database query using `PDO::FETCH_OBJ`. It contains users comment on a certain posts And i need to `echo` each individual values.How can i get the element values from this `array`?

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [posts] => lo;l;l ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [posts] => i am feeling well ! ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [posts] => it's 8 am in the morning .... ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [posts] => i am new here :) ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [posts] => farewell day !!!! ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [posts] => farewell day !!!! ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [posts] => farewell day !!!! ) [7] => stdClass Object ( [posts] => farewell day !!!! ) [8] => stdClass Object ( [posts] => bal ) [9] => stdClass Object ( [posts] => bal ) [10] => stdClass Object ( [posts] => halum ) )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($array as $key => $val){

     echo $val->posts;

}
```